# how to use turfjs to draw an arc via north east

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, turfjs

Im using `react-map-gl` and `turf`

in this image you could see the arc moves from source to destination via south . how can i change the angle of the arc so it could move from north.

[image: actual behaviour]

[image: expected behaviour]

the arc is drawn using the last method which is discussed in this thread https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1218 .

**Codesandbox** - https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-fix-ymk4r?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood your need, but if you want to basically draw an arc between points you could also do something like this:

```
const p1 = turf.point([-122.3811441, 37.6213129]);
const p2 = turf.point([-118.4107187, 33.9415889]);

const bearingToCenter = turf.bearing(p1, p2) + 90;
const midPoint = turf.center(turf.featureCollection([p1, p2]));
const arcRadius = 1000;

const theCenter = turf.destination(midPoint, arcRadius, bearingToCenter);

const bearing1 = turf.bearing(p1, theCenter);
const bearing2 = turf.bearing(p2, theCenter);

const arc = turf.lineArc(theCenter, arcRadius, bearing1 +180, bearing2 +180);
```

Clearly, the code is not perfect, but it's just a quick draft to give you the gist.

Comment: no , my question is how to change the angle of the arc not how to draw an arc , you can take a look at my codesandbox as im trying to achieve is to draw the arc which can move through north side not from south side. do you know how can i change the angle ?

Comment: [How to use center and lineArc to draw a curved line from PointA and PointB ?](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1218#issuecomment-592421977)